# Flutter image not showing on simulator - Exception: Invalid Image Data

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

Hello I'm trying to make a carousel on my app but the images are not showing. The code and error are below, would appreciate if anyone can help me out with this.

The error on my terminal:

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
Exception: Invalid image data

Code:

```
class CarouselBuild extends StatefulWidget {
  CarouselBuild({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CarouselBuild> createState() => _CarouselBuildState();
}

class _CarouselBuildState extends State<CarouselBuild> {
  final urlImages = [
    'https://unsplash.com/photos/VURwPtZqyF4',
    'https://unsplash.com/photos/oCZHIa1D4EU',
    'https://unsplash.com/photos/5-GNa303REg',
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CarouselSlider.builder(
      options: CarouselOptions(
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        autoPlay: true,
        aspectRatio: 2.0,
      ),
      itemCount: urlImages.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) {
        final urlImage = urlImages[index];
        return buildImage(urlImage, index);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget buildImage(String urlImage, int index) => Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: Image.network(
          urlImage,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your code but with image paths.

You have defined your image paths as:

```
final urlImages = [
   'https://unsplash.com/photos/VURwPtZqyF4',
   'https://unsplash.com/photos/oCZHIa1D4EU',
   'https://unsplash.com/photos/5-GNa303REg',
];
```

However, these are not the actual images, but only the Unsplash pages. The existing paths for your provided photos would be:

```
final urlImages = [
   'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578632767115-351597cf2477',
   'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1528360983277-13d401cdc186',
   'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534214526114-0ea4d47b04f2',
];
```